# The author of the question copycats an answer and approves it

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer, plagiarism

I wish there is something we can do about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746300/how-to-show-snackbar-at-top-of-the-screen), where the author [copycatted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31746589/1129332) the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31746370/1129332) and approved it.

He claims he did a change, when actually he edited the title to match his own application, and the parameter to match his own application. It is the same as if I told you that I built a ship for you, and you change its name and say you did the work.

Comment: That looks pretty nasty. plagiarizing an upvoted answer on your own question, thats a low blow.

Comment: Meta effect seems to have hit the plagiarist pretty hard, with the answer going from +3 to -1 in half an hour.

Comment: Additional note there also seems to be some edit karfuffel going on about the answer atm.

Comment: Yes, OP at one point removed the attribution which makes his behaviour even more despicable.

Comment: @DavidPostill I think a temporary suspension and removal of the answer is in order. But thats for the moderators to decide.

Comment: *He claims he did a change, when actually he edited the title to match his own app and the param to match his own app* - For what it's worth, this is actually fairly common place.

Comment: @Magisch +1 for "karfuffel".

Comment: Guys tell me one thing If i ask you **how much is 145 + 73 + 62**??? **calculate in your mind and tell the answer**. All will answer  280. But all will calculate differently in their ways but the answer will only be **280**

Comment: So i cant change the syntax or methods but what i have did is changed the line which will work for everyone. It like generalising the code so anybody just copy paste and it will work for them.

Comment: So tell me guys Did i have done wrong???

Comment: @Clairvoyant There are several things you could have done to make this not as bad. 1. Provide clear attribution from whom you took it in the original post, and not edit that out later. 2. You could have made your post community wiki instead of an  answer, 3. You could have provided the changes you made in a comment to the main answer instead of posting your own.

Comment: @Magisch tell me one thing. Does **SO** have a badge for questioning, answering and accepting own answer or not if it is correct???

Comment: @Clairvoyant The idea is that you answer your own question with your own answer that you came up with, not copy the answer of another person and then edit it only ever so slightly.

Comment: @Magisch - That was not copy paste. Explained you with an example.

Comment: @Clairvoyant Was you did was copypaste with only very minor changes and you even edited out the attribution later.

Comment: Slightly change in code would done so many things work done for you which i have did in my answer and it would work for anybody against the answer posted there. And your offending it.

Comment: I have never expected this as i am a follower of **SO** and coming regularly to **SO**.

Comment: @Clairvoyant add a (constructive) answer explaining your point of view.

Comment: @Clairvoyant Your behavior, to me, is like asking someone how to concatenate string "foo" with string "bar". Someone answers you with `concat(str1, str2)` and you say "No this is wrong it should be `concat("foo", "bar")`!" *Disclaimer: I don't code Android.* PS Stop abusing **bold text** please.

Comment: By far, the worst thing here is not the questionnable behaviour of 'malvoyant'. Worst thing is that, even caught with jam on its hands and mouth, he wouldn't admit doing anything wrong. ==>>> BAN.

Comment: We need a "Get The Pitchforks!" close reason.

Comment: Well done, meta effect!  Not only has the issue been addressed, but the question has also received an impressively thorough browbeating as well!  Because, as we all know, voting should be about your judgement of the author's character, rather than content.

Comment: The content is a copy, so what are you talking about... really ....

Comment: If i have did something like that what you guys are talking about then why i  have didn't answer to my other questions and accept them. I could do that also. What i did is correct from my point of view and i am just offending myself. I am not abusing anybody. But you guys making it so much big issue like i have killed somebody. **Be like professionals guys in coding a minute mistakes could make Billion to Million and Million to Zero also. So i would offend myself whether somebody support me or not.** Coding is my passion and in coding you cant do a single minute mistake.

Comment: @GameAlchemist - Talking about the *question*.

Comment: I love how we ended up forcing a Reversal badge and ~400 rep out of this for Adarsh

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure if there is a distinct flag for plagiarism, but I'm pretty sure that this warrants a flag as it's clearly plagiarism in my opinion. Raise a flag for Moderator attention with the details.

**Edit:** The author of the Answer that is subject in this Question has accepted Edits to his Answer adding Attribution, and changed the Acceptance to the actually highly rated Answer.

Comment: FYI the OP accepted the other answer because their own answer was deleted by meta effect. It was not entirely their own decision. Probably for the better anyway...

Comment: umm....answer is not accepted ATM (Wednesday, 21 October 2015 7:23 AM GMT)

Comment: @DroidDev the original plagiarized Answer by the author of the question got deleted as consequence of the meta effect.

Comment: @Magisch: Right, but the other answer is not accepted (as I write this, apparently the situation is fluid).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, DroidDev: As far as I can tell, the OP begrudgingly accepted the answer after their own was deleted by vote, and they then unaccepted it, presumably out of frustration with this whole thing. I don't blame them.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yeah. The downvotes on the *question* are just wild. -39/+15. Sure, 15 * 5 - 39 * 2 is only -3 so it's not as bad as it looks, but yikes...

Comment: -39? Jesus christ @T.J.Crowder people are overreacting to this

Comment: Don't you hate it when people overreact to trivial issues that are otherwise easily remedied?

Comment: @Bob I was in that boat too as my answer evidences, but what I had in mind was maybe like answer deletion and a 2 or 3 day posting ban, just to see that it stings. The veritable shitstorm hes getting right now is unjustified.

Answer (score 52):

**This is not a clear-cut case of plagiarism.** The author of the "plagiarized" answer actually gave credit in the original revision of his answer (posted July 31<sup>st</sup>, 2015),

> I have solved with help of Adarsh Yadav answer with little bit of
>   changes which are:
>
> ```
> Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Had a snack at Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
> View view = snack.getView();
> FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
> params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
> view.setLayoutParams(params);
> snack.show();
> ```

In the next revision made on August 13<sup>th</sup>, the OP made this revision:

> I have solved the problem with little bit of changes which are:

This just looks like a case of someone who's treating Stack Overflow as a discussion forum rather than a Q&A site, and is treating his answer as if it were just another post in a discussion thread.

I would just edit the appropriate attribution back in and politely explain to the OP why it's important to give such attribution for work that is based off of someone else's

Then that's it. Call it a day. Unless the OP then continues to try to remove attribution, I wouldn't bother raising a moderator flag for this.

Comment: I disagree respectfully.

Comment: @Magisch: What part do you disagree with?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett      The removal of attribution and his accepting his own answer  indicated malicious intent to me.

Comment: @Magisch The removal of the attribution is a little bit douchey, but other than that I don't see what all the fuss is about here.

Comment: @DavidG Removal of attribution on a copied post is flat out plagiarism in my opinion. Add the accepting of his own answer and I think thats worthy of a suspension and answer deletion.

Comment: @Magisch a lot of users on SO still don't understand that it's not a discussion forum. People make innocent mistakes all the time. Given that attribution was originally given, and that it wasn't removed until about 2 weeks later, I would give the OP the benefit of doubt in this case. I would also like to point out that it's **not an exact copy** answer, it's based off the original in part, but is not exactly the same.

Comment: @Bob If upon seeing it he would have admitted it was a bad idea and took appropiate action, I would be inclined to agree. But seeing as he started raising a fuss on the question comments, im inclined to disagree.

Comment: @Magisch Calm down! The answer posted was *different* from the original so it's certainly not worthy of being deleted (or even downvoted so heavily imo). Admittedly, I would have commented on the original rather than post my own but what you are asking for is over the top.

Comment: @DavidG Maybe, and thats why I don't get to make the decision on my own. I explained why I feel this way, if consensus is not with me on that then oh well, my opinion doesn't have to be yours.

Comment: User Clairvoyant turned out not to be, but I can't see ill-intent. I also believe the downvotes are unwarranted. Not only the answer, but the question has taken a pounding. Is it a bad question? Is a future search going to take any notice of it due to the downvotes? Comment and move on. It works for the OP, so why downvotes? Anyway, the Accept has been changed.

Comment: @BillWoodger I have not downvoted the question and I revoked my downvote of the answer when he accepted the other one. Apparently some people take it out on everything though.

Comment: @Magisch I think that shows thought on your part.

Comment: @theB Haha I did wonder about that!

Comment: @BillWoodger The quality of the question has nothing to do with the quality of the answer he provided. And the original downvote on the answer was not for strictly quality reasons, but because I interpret it to be plagiarism. Now that he has re-added attribution and corrected the acceptance, I no longer find this to be the case.

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree with Bob, since finding and eliminating plagiarism is kind of his thing. (Thanks @BillWoodger for the copy-edit on this comment)

Comment: @Bob I edited my Answer to this meta question to reflect a change of behaviour of the accused.

Comment: I'd post an answer, but I don't want to be accused of plagiarizing Bob's answer.

Comment: @BoltClock - it is pretty tempting to plagiarize one of Bob's answers isn't it. :)

Comment: Guys I appologize for the answer i have accepted but because his answer was not working for me and i have to do some modification to work it thats why i have posted the answer with acceptance so anybody who will search get the right solution. My intention was that only, i have asked other questions also but never posted my solution with acceptance.

Comment: And the other thing was there was an **Badge** also for questioning, answering and accepting own answer. so wouldn't we do that thing???

Comment: @Clairvoyant yes, if it's _your_ answer...

Comment: +1 - We should all be a bit more laid back so that this site doesnt become more dedicated to bashing people by downvotes instead of concentrating on topics. 
The reaction on the post I believe is a bit harsh especially as many of the reactions were done after the OP complied to the requests of this meta post. So on one side the correctional intentions succeeded but were followed by punishing. Hope this doesn't become standard on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Clairvoyant you asked how to show a `snackbar` at the top and your question was answered; the important part was the code surrounding `params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;`. The line you modified had nothing to do with the answer, you merely applied the solution to your specific code where some strings or variable names are different. Your answer is in no way better than the original one, it is only specific to your app. A different user wouldn't benefit more from it. Thus, why should yours be the accepted one? It is a mere copy of the original with some unimportant changes.

Comment: @enzi - It is not working on Coordinate Layout and RelativeLayout. So thats why haven't accepted. It would only work in LinearLayout.

Comment: @Clairvoyant You did not ask for it to work on a specific layout. People looking for this solution might be using `LinearLayout`, in which case your own answer would be "worse" if we were to rate the importance of the layout (and for other people it would be better). Also, I do not mean to bash you, I am merely trying to explain why there is so much fuss about this. It would be easy for everyone to leave out some small details about the usage of code, then copy the correct answer and modify it to work with said code. This must not be the way we use this site.

Comment: @enzi- If you are saying my answer would be worse then the other solution which have been suggested to me should have downvote rather than upvote. I haven't accepted the answer but i have upvoted him for the idea he suggested me. But people make it as big issue because of my answer with acceptance. I am following rule of SO i can accept my answer which i have did and the result was this.