# Why did this question get this many downvotes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I'm genuinely curious what is so bad about this question that it got this many downvotes.

[How to show Snackbar at top of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31746300/3151675)

I checked the edit history as well, but I'm still clueless. Is this just bad luck/a sad form of peer pressure?

Comment: My guess is that this is extended meta effect from OP trying something shady. Let me dig around a little

Comment: Definitely possible. It's still unfair IMO.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308392/the-author-of-the-question-copycats-an-answer-and-approves-it

Comment: The Meta effect is undoubtedly part of it, but votes on that question *did* [trickle in over time](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31746300/timeline/). Hard to say whether they trickled in from people seeing the Meta question Hans linked, but rather doubtful that many people are digging up old Meta questions.

Comment: Unfunny how OP bumped his question several times by making useless edits to the question title. Surely added some good vibes to the question.

Comment: *Wait for another meta effect on the linked post...*

Comment: that question is at +86/-130, they are still in the green, reputation wise. Maybe your meta question about it can tip the balance ...

Comment: I knew that was suspicious :o

Comment: Also worth a thought: Asking for help in violating established user interface guidelines often attracts down-votes to echo objection. I don't think this is a valid reason to vote on a question, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't happen.

Comment: Curiously, [answers that recommend *not* violating established user interface guidelines also attract downvotes to echo objection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862315/changing-the-color-of-the-title-bar-in-winform/11875375#11875375), @IInspectable :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: Technically, though, one could argue, that your answer doesn't address the question that was asked, and that it wasn't down-voted because it promotes following UI guidelines. I predict that the voting would be different had your answer been along the lines of: *"This is how you do the wrong thing. Try not to do the wrong thing."* Of course, no one would read the second part, but that's a different matter altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HansPassant pointed out, the question's author plagiarized the top rated answer and accepted it as its own.

Here are the details:

[The author of the question copycats an answer and approves it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308392/)